# PDFKit in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, pdf, xcode4.4

I am trying to install PDFKit framework in Objective-C. I have x-code 4.4.1 but am unable to see the PDFKit Framework in build phases. Is the framework discontinued from iOS 5 ?
I want to use the the framework to view and annotate a pdf. 
Can anyone let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it was ever available in ios. Why don't you search for it in apple's reference manual for ios?

Comment: It is available. Can you check this link https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pdfkit.html

Comment: That's the OS X reference, not the iOS reference.

Answer (score 1):

PDFKit is now available on iOS 11. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378679/how-to-use-pdfkit-ios-11-to-open-pdf-file/45496353#45496353) answer on Objective-C implementation